# Win vs Web: The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, oracle, dll

I'm trying to open a connection to Oracle from c#.
I've seen this error a couple of times on the forums with possible solutions.  And these solutions did help me - for a WinForm app.

However, if I take my same coding (that works in WinForms) and I put into an ASP.net application, I get the error in the title.

The command that generates this is:

```
OracleConnection oc = new OracleConnection(ConnectionString);
```

Additional information:
I have a reference to Oracle.DataAccess (version 2.111.6.20)
I've copied the required dll's to my bin directory (oci.dll, ociw32.dll, orannzsbb11.dll, oraocci11.dll, oraociicus11.dll, OraOps11w.dll).

These are the same DLL's that are working in WinForms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error mostly comes due to the incompatible processor architecture(`32bit` or `64`) of the application and the `Oracle ODAC` dll that you have added as reference. It might work in the client app but not in the web app because you might be running the Asp.net application in incompatible bit version `32` or `64`.

In case if you have hosted the site in `IIS` you will have to check the bit version IIS is configured to run.

**EDIT**

If the above solution didnt solve your issue, Check if you have `Oracle Client` installed in your machine. Some database operations needs at least Oracle Client installation(Oracle Express or Enterprise etc). Not having the installation might throw the same exception.

Comment: I've tried running the app as both 64-bit and Any CPU (in VS 2012).  I also tried to Publish it and running in IIS with the setting to allow 32 bit apps.  Same error.

Comment: @user1208908 Are you using 32 or 64 bit ODAC ?

Comment: @user1208908 Have you installed oracle client in you machine ? if then is that 32 or 64 bit ?

Comment: If you want to alleviate these issues, switch to Oracle's managed ODP.Net provider; you no longer need to worry about the underlying Oracle installation. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html

Comment: @user1208908 Since you have installed 64bit Oracle client, Did you try running the IIS in 64bit ?? you have mentioned that you configured the IIS to 32bit ? then it will not work.

Comment: The original setup did not have the Oracle client, but since posting I have tested on machine with Oracle XE 11.2.  That seems to work.  Do I have to install Oracle XE on all the machines where this will be deployed, or are there a workaround?

Comment: @Allen Elder: As far as I know the Oracle.DataAccess are the ODP.Net provider.

Comment: @user1208908 You can also use Oracle Instant Client.

Comment: I did try to install Instant Client but not working.  Maybe I did something wrong.  After installing OracleXE it did start to work.  Would be great if it can work without this installation - I did double check and I am using ODP.net as suggested by Allan Elder.